# How to fix NameError: in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am building code to find the largest prime factor of a number. I have written the code. Please point out the changes that need to be made to the code. Any help is appreciated !!

I have tried removing the class declaration and just declaring two functions as mentioned in the code but still the `NameError: 'isPrime' used before declaration` still persists.

```
class Soln(object):

    def isPrime(self,num):
        c=0
        if (num<2):
            return False
        else:
            for x in range(1,num):
                if (num%x == 0):
                    c+=1
                if (c>1):
                    return False
                else:
                    return True    

    def nLargest(self,n):
        for x in range(n,0,-1):
            if(isPrime(x)):
                print ("\nLargest Prime Factor is"+str(x))
                exit()

a=Soln()

a.nLargest(12)
```

The output should be 3 but it gives

> NameError: isPrime used before declaration.

Comment: Replace `if(isPrime(x)):` by `if(self.isPrime(x)):` and it will work. You have initiated the methods with `self` in the class so you would need to call them using `self.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use rhis code:

```
def nLargest(self,n):
    for x in range(n,0,-1):
        if(self.isPrime(x)):
            print ("\nLargest Prime Factor is"+str(x))
            exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have 'global' method `isPrime` defined. You probably want to use the one, which is in the class `Soln`. In order to do this, you can write:

`self.isPrime(x)` (while calling from another method of `Soln`)

or
`a.isPrime(x)` (while calling on Soln object `a` from outside of this object)

or make the method static and use:

`Soln.isPrime(x)`